# Python script to find large folders

Tags: python, recursion, python-3.x, exception-handling, file-system

I wrote this script a few days ago to find all files which were taking up over a certain threshold of memory on the hard drive.  A hard drive on one of my computers had just 6 GB left, so I needed to clean some space up.  I used this to identify bulky folders to find out where the problem was.

Is there anything I could have done better?  I'm particularly displeased with the exception handling in the `get_folder_size` function, since I ended up handling the same exception twice, just at different levels.  Couldn't think of a way around it off hand, though.  Also, efficiency was an issue with this script.  I know I could've invented some framework to keep track of all the folders previously scanned, but that seemed like a bit too monumental of an effort to make for such a trivial script.  The recursion was much easier to implement.

Any and all suggestions are welcome!

```
import os

BYTES_IN_GIGABYTE = 1073741824
GIGABYTE_DISPLAY_LIMIT = 2
ACCESS_ERROR_CODE = 13

def get_folder_size(filepath):
    size = os.path.getsize(filepath)
    try:
        for item in os.listdir(filepath):
            item_path = os.path.join(filepath, item)
            try:
                if os.path.isfile(item_path):
                    size += os.path.getsize(item_path)
                elif os.path.isdir(item_path):
                    size += get_folder_size(item_path)
            except OSError as err:
                if err.errno == ACCESS_ERROR_CODE:
                    print('Unable to access ' + item_path)
                    continue
                else:
                    raise
    except OSError as err:
        if err.errno != ACCESS_ERROR_CODE:
            raise
        else:
            print('Unable to access ' + filepath)
    return size

def get_all_folder_sizes(root_filepath):
    folders = []
    for item in os.walk(root_filepath):
        if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(root_filepath, item[0])):
            folders.append([item[0], get_folder_size(item[0])])
    return folders

def convert_bytes_to_gigabytes(bytes):
    return bytes / BYTES_IN_GIGABYTE

def main():
    folder_sizes = get_all_folder_sizes('C:\\')
    folder_sizes.sort()
    for folder in folder_sizes:
        gigabytes = convert_bytes_to_gigabytes(folder[1])
        if gigabytes > GIGABYTE_DISPLAY_LIMIT:
            print(folder[0] + ' = ' + format(gigabytes, '.2f') + ' GB')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: For lisibility purposes, I'd rather read `BYTES_IN_GIGABYTE = 2**30`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ACCESS_ERROR_CODE` is `errno.EACCES`.

`BYTES_IN_GIGABYTE` is clearer as `2**30`. That's transparent enough that the constant and `convert_bytes_to_gigabytes` aren't needed, so I'd just write `folder[1] / 2**30`.

`GIGABYTE_DISPLAY_LIMIT` sounds like an *upper* limit to display. How about `GIGABYTE_DISPLAY_THRESHOLD` instead?

To reduce the opportunity for unit confusion, I'd keep the size and the threshold in bytes, and only convert to GB when printing.

You may want `folder_sizes.sort(reverse=True)` to get the largest ones first.

`get_all_folder_sizes` recurses over directories twice: once in `os.walk` and once in `get_folder_size`. This takes time quadratic in the tree depth, so it may be slow. Can you do the recursion just once, by returning a generator of `(size, path)` pairs, and recursing on subdirectories?

You can avoid the two `try` blocks by getting directory size in the same place as file size. (Then you don't even need `isfile`.)

The `continue` in the inner exception handler is redundant.

Comment: Thanks for your tips!  I tried `errno.EACCESS`, but for some reason the comparison wasn't working.  I'll try it again.